# Player movement calculation for dynamic FPS (frame per second)

Tags: javascript, game-engine

If a game is running at 177FPS or 22FPS, how is the player movements calculated? I'm trying to do this in Javascript:

```
setInterval(update, 0);

function update() {
     player_x++;
}
```

[image: preview of problem]

Problem is if the player will be move faster/slower according to the frame rate. How would I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) when available (which will get you the best frame rate possible in modern browsers) and setTimeout when not. Then base your players position on the time since the animation started:

```
// Anonymous function used to make variables declared inside it not global
// This avoids conflicts in case variables with the same names are used
// in other scripts
(function(){

    // This checks for the requestAnimationFrame in each browser and store the first
    // it finds into requestAnimationFrame. If none are found it uses setTimeout
    // Attempting 60 frames per second.
    // It's taken from Paul Irish's blog: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
    // and you can use it as is
    var requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
        return window.requestAnimationFrame    || 
               window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
               window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
               window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
               window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
               function(callback){
                   setTimeout(function(){ callback((new Date).getTime()); }, 1000/60);
               };
    })();

    var speed = 60; // pixels per second

    // This is used so that we only divide by 1000 once instead of every frame
    var calc = speed/1000;

    // Store the current time in start_time
    var start_time = (new Date).getTime();

    // This function is self invoking. It is wrapped in parenthesis and called immediately
    // time is passed in by requestAnimationFrame
    (function draw(time){
        // Calculate the new x position based on the current time
        var pos = (time - start_time)*calc;

        // Update the player's position
        // In my JSFiddle I update the style.left of a div
        player_x = pos;

        // Now that this frame is done request another frame.
        // draw will be called again before that frame is rendered
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    })();

})();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/3SGFC/)

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for but can this be made into a function? There a lot of annonimius function and I not exactly sure whats going on here. Can you basically simplify this please?

Comment: @CezarisLT I will add some comments throughout it to make it more understandable.

Comment: @CezarisLT Let me know if what I've added is helpful.

Comment: @paulp-r-o Yes thank you very much, comments helped. I have to alter it to my project. At first I had a function that run's as much as possible and this was in a set interval. Inside this I would run update() function and this would move my player. This is slightly different.

Comment: If you could look at this JSFidle and try and implement the gravity into requestAnimationFrame would be great I don't really know how to do it. Thank you in advance. http://jsfiddle.net/kcyWC/47/

Answer (score 1):

Try using a timer function instead, so that the player moves based on time and not changes in frames...

Comment: I have should of mention this, but I do NOT want a fixed frame rate because to my understanding that's what  timer function do.

Answer (score 1):

The distance is equal to speed (constant) and time. Depending on the framerate (in Hz) the time t = `1 / framerate` will vary.

To put this into code: measure the time between subsequent frames and use that time to calculate the distance.

Sometimes a better idea is to have a background thread (in JavaScript you can use `setInterval()` as suggested by `CezarisLT` and use constant time. However in practice you still need to measure the time between subsequent invocations because `setInterval()` is not guaranteed to run exactly at scheduled time (long running functions, high CPU usage).

BTW your code is overly verbose and won't compile:

```
setInterval(update, 0)

function update() {
     player_x++;
}
```